# Dynamically Changing Table Cell Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement both vertical and horizontal scrollable table using two tables from this [jfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3vzrunkt/).
 The table will display data from mysql database.
 The header of the first table is combined with the body of the second table. CSS is used to align the two tables together. 
 Now I want the cells in a specific column to be equal width depending on the width of the longest cell.For example using pseudo code below.

```html
if(col1.row1.cellWidth > col1.row2.cellWidth)
{
   col1.cellWidth = col1.row1.cellWidth;
}
```

Below is the html table code:

```html
<div class="table-header" id="headerdiv">
  <table id="headertable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20%">
             <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Department</strong></th>
    <th class="center"><strong>Unit</strong></th>
    <th class="center"><strong>Time Booked</strong></th>
    <th class="center"><strong>Purpose</strong></th>
                            </tr>
           </table>
    </div>
 
  <div class="table-body" onscroll="document.getElementById('headerdiv').scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;">
        <table id="bodytable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <?php
           if($stmt->execute()) {
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                     <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['first_name']."  ".$rows['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['department']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['unit']; ?></td>
      <td class="center" >
                           <input name="booking_time" type="datetime-local" id="booking_time" value="<?php echo myDate($rows['booking_time']); ?>" size="15">
                         </td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['purpose']; ?></td>
                         </tr>
                 </tbody>
                        
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?> 
</table>
</div>
```

Below is the css code

```css
.outer-container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 300px;
    bottom:80px;
    overflow: visible;

}
.inner-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.table-header {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.table-body {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: inherit;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 padding-right: 16px;
}
.header-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: left;
}


.col1, .col3, .col4, .col5 {
    width:120px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be tables?

Comment: @Carol I have to display data from a mysql database using the table.

Comment: I think flex may be your answer http://flexbox.io/#/ https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ http://autoprefixer.github.io/